# Beautifulsoup4 - Getting error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get the product title from an amazon url-https://www.amazon.in/BATA-Fenny-Sneakers-7-India-8219990/dp/B07P8PMS25/ref=asc_df_B07P8PMS25/?tag=googleshopdes-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=397006879402&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=2284563689588211961&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1007824&hvtargid=pla-837374864561&psc=1&ext_vrnc=hi. I tried this code

```
from bs4 import *
import requests
head={'user-agent':'betbargain/android-7.0/0.0.5'}
amaurl=input('Enter amazon url')
amazinfo=requests.get(amaurl,headers=head)
amasoup=BeautifulSoup(amazinfo.text,'lxml')
amatit=amasoup.find("span", attrs={"id":'productTitle'}).string.strip()
print(amatit)
```

But when I input the url it says-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/rauna/Desktop/bb.py", line 7, in <module>
    amatit=amasoup.find("span", attrs={"id":'productTitle'}).string.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

I have no idea why this has happened. Please tell me where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the search to `<h1>` with `id="title"`:

```
from bs4 import *
import requests
head={'user-agent':'betbargain/android-7.0/0.0.5'}
# amaurl=input('Enter amazon url')
amaurl = 'https://www.amazon.in/BATA-Fenny-Sneakers-7-India-8219990/dp/B07P8PMS25/ref=asc_df_B07P8PMS25/?tag=googleshopdes-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=397006879402&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=2284563689588211961&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1007824&hvtargid=pla-837374864561&psc=1&ext_vrnc=hi'
amazinfo=requests.get(amaurl,headers=head)
amasoup=BeautifulSoup(amazinfo.text,'lxml')
amatit=amasoup.find("h1", attrs={"id":'title'}).get_text(strip=True)  # <-- change to <h1 id="title">
print(amatit)
```

Prints:

```
BATA Men's Fenny Sneakers
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Raunanza/d878ee32d482e382f30f53c38fb706b3#file-ama-py This code I have copied from a website. It's working but I have no idea why and how. Can you please explain.

Answer (score 1):

If `find` does not find anything, it will return `None`. Have a look at [the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find). You have to check if `find` has found anything before doing something with the result.

Also instead of `.string`, I think you want `str()`.

Try this instead:

```py
from bs4 import *
import requests

head = {'user-agent':'betbargain/android-7.0/0.0.5'}
amaurl = input('Enter amazon url')
amazinfo = requests.get(amaurl,headers=head)
amasoup = BeautifulSoup(amazinfo.text,'lxml')

findResult = amasoup.find("span", attrs={"id":'productTitle'})
amatit = ""
if (findResult != None): # Added a check for findResult being None
    amatit = str(findResult).strip() # Changed .string to str()
print(amatit)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from bs4 import *
import requests
head={'user-agent':'betbargain/android-7.0/0.0.5'}
amaurl=input('Enter amazon url')
amazinfo=requests.get(amaurl,headers=head)
amasoup=BeautifulSoup(amazinfo.text,'lxml')
amatit=str(amasoup.find("span", attrs={"id":'productTitle'})).strip()
print(amatit)
```